# How to update 10.4.11 OS X?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to update 10.4.11 OS X to the newest version of OS X? I have Mac Pro (2 x 2 GHz Dual-Core Intel Xeon with 1 GB ram).

Comment: Mavericks system requirements are at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to at least buy Snow Leopard to upgrade. You can buy it from the [Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) for $20, and then the upgrade from that to Mavericks is free.

Answer (score 0):

Check the specifications of your mac. It appears that you are running a MacPro1,1. This machine will only upgrade as far as Lion (10.7). If your machine isn't listed it can't run it. You would also need to add RAM.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5842